# Why wont dev C run this script? It's not liking my vector declaration for some reason

Tags: c++

I'm busy working through my C++ book and cant seem to get this to run without the error "[Error] 'vector' was not declared in this scope"

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main(){
string word;
string previous;
string current;

vector<string> dislikes(4);
dislikes [0] = "bob";
dislikes [1] = "cat";
dislikes [2] = "pineapple";
dislikes [3] = "stackoverflow";

while(cin >> current){
for(i = 0; i<dislikes.size(); ++i){
    if(current==dislike[i]){
        cout << "BLEEP ";}

    else{cout << current << " "}

}   
    previous = current;
}

}
return 0;
}
```

Comment: You need to `#include <vector>`

Comment: You also need to `#include <string>`

Comment: I've never had problems with any scripts that were missing #include <string>. As for #include <vector>, I'm surprised my book didnt mention this.

Comment: @ThePeskyWabbit, Probably because it's happened to have been included by another header, but you cannot rely on that behaviour. I've seen things around this subject change lately.

Comment: @ThePeskyWabbit: I'd also be surprised if your book didn't mention it. Chances are good that it did, and you just missed it. Sometimes they'll tell you things like this when they first introduce a topic, but then to save space omit them in future examples.

Answer (score 4):

You need to include the header file for the vector type:

```
#include <vector>
```

In C++, everything must be declared before it is used in your code and declarations for the standard library are in the [standard library header files](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/header).

Comment: That is not entirely true as you can use forward declaring in certain cases, but you are right in this particular case, so I voted your comment up.

Comment: When you forward *declare* you are *declaring* you just haven't defined it yet.

Comment: Ah yes, sorry, I read define for some obscure reason. It is too morning'ish in here. ;-)